# Dynamic JQuery function to change HTML in various DIVs

Tags: jquery

I am building a small application for my company (I'm not a pro in development, just doing it because I'm the only person they have who is technically inclined). The nuts and bolts are these: We have one product page with items pulled from database via PHP/MYSQL. Right now there are only some 15 products but that could go way up.

For each product displayed on the page I am using CSS div classes as opposed to IDs. The product thumbnail image is generated dynamically, but I want a color picker to appear for each item shown on the product list page, and keep in mind that not all color options for each item are the same. I want someone to be able to click on a color picker for a particular item shown on a screen with many other items, but change only the thumbnail for the item whose color picker was clicked (so that they can see the item they're interested in, but in the color they click on).

What I have so far is this. Please help!!!

```
Product Page

<div class="flex-container">
<div class="thumbnail" data-id="1">
<a href="product.php?id=1">
<img src="images/coletti_thumb.jpg" alt="" height="180"></a>
<h3>Coletti</h3></div>
<div data-id="2"><a href="product.php?id=2">
<img src="images/R1GVA52BNW_thumb.jpg" alt="" height="180"></a>
<h3>Vail</h3>
<div title="Brushed Nickel" data-id="button_2" class="colorSwatch" style="background-image: url('images/Brushed+Nickel_swatch.jpg')"></div>
<div title="Driftwood" data-id="button_2" class="colorSwatch" style="background-image: url('images/Driftwood_swatch.jpg')"></div>
<div title="Matte Black" data-id="button_2" class="colorSwatch" style="background-image: url('images/Matte+Black_swatch.jpg')"></div>
<div title="Matte White" data-id="button_2" class="colorSwatch" style="background-image: url('images/Matte+White_swatch.jpg')"></div>
<div title="Oil Rubbed Bronze" data-id="button_2" class="colorSwatch" style="background-image: url('images/Oil+Rubbed+Bronze_swatch.jpg')"></div></div>
```

For the JQUERY I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorSwatch").on("click", function() {
    $(".thumbnail"+$(this).data('content-id')).replaceWith(various STuff)
})
```

Clearly I'm confused as to how to control just one div with so many divs of the same name involved in the process. Any advice would be welcome!!!

Comment: There's no `data-content-id` attribute in the `colorSwatch` DIV. And you have no elements with `id="thumbnail<id>"`

Comment: I don't have the thumbnails set up as IDs but rather as classes because my understanding is that using the same IDs on a page is a no-no and wouldn't work. So I have a bunch of classes with all the same name.

Comment: But your code is using `$("#thumbnail" +  $(this).data('content-id'))` to access elements with different IDs.

Comment: So you should have `id="thumbnail1"`, `id="thumbnail2"`, etc.

Comment: Now it should be `class="thumbnail1"` instead of `class="thumbnail"`

Comment: That was my first attempt at trying to figure out how to delineate between which id I was after. What I was thinking was to attach the product ID to each data-id on the swatch and the thumbnail, but if we wind up with thousands of products it could turn into a nightmare. So now I just don't know what to do.

Comment: If you want to match `data-id`, you should use `$(".thumbnail[data-id="+$(this).data("content-id")+"]")`

Comment: Wouldn't my HTML and page buffering take a hit if I had hundreds of products all on the same page with different jquery functions to handle changing their thumbnail image?

Comment: Why would you need different jQuery functions? That's the whole reason for creating the selector dynamically using `.data()`.

Comment: I think I see where you're headed with that. Lemme try!!

Comment: You've got the right general idea, you're just missing the details.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! It worked. It's difficult to see how I couldn't have figured that out, but under so much pressure to get it working I guess I wasn't thinking. Thank you!!